# Meta data migration problem for S-control?

Tags: s-control

I have a old organization with S-control metadata now I want to move these s-control into new organization but I am getting "S-control is not enable for current organization"  I know this is because we can not create s-control now because it is deprecated in 2010 and replace by visualforce pages.

But I want to move S-control, Is there are any way to move these s-control?

Answer (score 0):

It was the case that if you have a managed package on the instance containing the S-Control that was created before February 1st, 2010 then you should be able to distribute the S-Control using that package.

Unfortunately if you do not have a package created before that date then you will be unable to distribute the S-Control. I'm also unsure as to whether the exception to S-Controls within packages created before that date still stands.

Here is a useful post regarding this: https://developer.salesforce.com/page/S-Control_Deprecation - although it is now 6 years old and the grandfathering exception may no longer be valid.